# How to set SplashScreen after create build

Tags: ionic-framework

I create a blank project in ionic. I also set splash screen in android platform. I can change the timing for this screen. All goes good.

But what if I want to set splash screen from by database at the time of installing this app. Is it possible or is there any other way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@gautam It's not possible in Ionic or even any other mobile app developement platform 
But you can do like reduce the time of splash screen to zero(0) and in device ready function you can call image from your database.